# Packaging maven project and external jar and property files for GIT upload

Tags: git, maven, pom.xml

I have a maven project which requires external config.properties file and an external `ABC.jar`.

I have placed the `config.properties` in `src/main/resources` and the external jar in `src/main/lib`.
I have configured the external jar to my project using buildpath->configure build path->add external library.

I read using `FileInputStream`.
But now I need to upload my code to GIT repository for which i need to load the external jar and properties file from the classpath.
I googled and found that I have to create a repository to store my external files and jar.
It would be helpful if I can look at a sample pom file to load my external jar and any idea to load my properties file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your property files right where it is in your local Git repo that you would then push to any Git repo hosting service you want (provided those properties don't include sensitive data)

But your external jar should simply be declare as a dependency in your pom.xml.
It should not be part of your git repo, or at least with a .gitignore file which would explicitly exclude any jar.

See [this article](https://softwarecave.org/2014/06/14/adding-external-jars-into-maven-project/) for more:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>evalpostfix</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If that external jar is available at one or more public repositories, that is enough.